# how to exclude test projects from continuous deployment

Tags: azure-devops

I have a build definition in VSTS and I want the unit test projects to be run as part of the build, do I then need to include those dlls in the deployment to the Azure web app? surely they are no longer needed after the build.

Comment: Don't publish them as artifacts and they won't be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

No matter you are going to use Release or not, you could only copy the files that you need and publish them:

[image]

If you are going to use TFS Release to deploy, then in Release definition, you can just select the build artifact. If you want to deploy in build definition, you can add deploy task after `Copy files` and deploy from the target folder in `Copy files` task.